# Javascript simple code object and function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to java script i have small problem this little code it's not working 
it's regarding object and function

```
var person = {
firstName : "kevin",
lastName : "sandigo"}

function getFullName() {
return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}


alert(person.getFullName());
```

Comment: I've offered you a couple options in my comment. Check them out and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your object into the function, and use that argument to access its properties:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "kevin",
    lastName: "sandigo"
};

function getFullName (obj) {
    return obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
}

alert( getFullName(person) );
```

---

If you want to create a class that you can re-use, you'll have to declare the function on the `prototype`:

```
function Person (firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};

var kevin = new Person("kevin", "sandigo");

alert( kevin.getFullName() );
```

Comment: it's very helpful and i want focus prototype method

Answer (score 3):

If you want the function to be a method on that particular object:

```
var kevin = {firstName: "kevin", lastName: "sandigo"}

person.getfullName = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + person.lastName
}

alert(kevin.getFullName())
```

Alternatively, if you want a more class-like approach

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName
  this.lastName  = lastName
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + person.lastName
}

var kevin = new Person("kevin", "sandigo")

alert(kevin.getFullName())
```

Comment: var person = {
    firstName : "kevin",
    lastName : "sandigo"
    }

    function getFullName() {
    return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
    }

    alert(getFullName());

above code wrong or not good usage ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `this` in your function but `this` refers to the object calling the function ... in this case, the window object.

You have two options for accessing values in your function. One method was mentioned in another comment... pass the object to the function:

```
var person = {
  "firstName" : "Kevin",
  "lastName"  : "Sandigo"
};

function getFullName(obj){
  return obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
}

alert(getFullName(person));
```

The other option is to pass the object in as the context to the function. This is done using the `call` method. Example:

```
var person = {
  "firstName" : "Kevin",
  "lastName"  : "Sandigo"
};

function getFullName(){
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}

alert(getFullName.call(person));
```